# Store spring message tag in variable

Tags: spring, freemarker

Is it possible to store the spring tag in a variable?

```
<@spring.message messageKey/>
```

I would like to concat this into a String

```
<#assign a = <@spring.message messageKey/> + "something">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way to do it. 
<#assign a ><@spring.message messageKey />

Answer (score 2):

I think that you want to store the tag value instead of spring tag. Try with this:

<@spring.message text="Enter your text here" var="mymessage">

${mymessage }

Comment: That tag only takes one parameter=